# what does もういわない mean?

Tags: hiragana

what does もういわない mean?
I got this message from someone and i dont think it means what I think...

Comment: Context? Literally it might mean "I won't talk about that anymore"

Comment: Funnily, [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#ja|en|%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%82%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) translates it to “Say again,” which is completely wrong.  Where did the negation go?

Comment: The [Bing translator](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/) translates it to "Another one" which is even further out. I recommend [babelfish](http://babelfish.yahoo.com) or [babylon](http://translation.babylon.com/japanese/to-english/) if that was the reason you were having problems as Google translate just isn't as good as those sites for Japanese-English.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto is it possible that perhaps Google Translate tried to interpret it as a negative question? I.e. "Won't you say it again?"(suggestive/requesting) which somehow became "Say again"(imperative)

Comment: @Flaw: Ah, that is plausible.

Answer (score 6):

I would venture "I won't say anymore."

If you were asking the same thing over and over, "I won't say it again" is a possibility.